# How to get the output of unique occurrences value with regex filter in HH:MM format in a list?

Tags: python

I have a list in HH:MM:SS like this :

```
a=['08:54:53', '08:54:53', '08:54:54', '08:54:54', '08:55:20', '08:55:20', '08:55:20', '08:55:22', '08:55:23', '08:55:23']
```

I want to get the return output in HH:MM with count from the list a. 
Like this:

```
08:54 occurs 4 times, 08:55 occurs 6 times
```

And please NOTE that the a list can have a vary result in HH:MM:SS in different time, not just the 2 unique 08:54 and 08:55, because i need to filter from a log file, so the HH:MM:SS from list a does not have a fixed occurrences HH:MM.

I have built a regex to match the HH:MM:SS(any SS) but i don't know how to apply to filter the list.

```
pattern=re.compile("^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:..$")
```

Thank you for reading

Comment: Are regexes mandatory here? There are other ways, without using regexes, that might be less complicated.

Comment: @TrebledJ i think regex does not mandatory cause i just dunno the other ways. Can you provide ur solution? thanks!

Comment: Is the point that you want to remove non-HH:MM:SS values from the list?  If so, can you post a more realistic example input list?

Comment: @LuatDangLeTrong Ah alright. I wrote up an answer. Ever heard of this joke: "*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.*" :)

Comment: @TrebledJ thanks haha, yes, i've never heard of that, just get into an internship in python and totally fresh :D, will definitely remember that :D.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're filtering a log file, I'll assume that the timestamps are chronological. Then you can use `itertools.groupby` to group items with similar hour-minute keys.

```
import itertools
import time


a = ['08:54:53', '08:54:53', '08:54:54', '08:54:54', '08:55:20', '08:55:20', '08:55:20', '08:55:22', '08:55:23', '08:55:23']


def hour_minute_key(t: str):
    s = time.strptime(t, '%H:%M:%S')
    return s.tm_hour, s.tm_min


for t, group in itertools.groupby(a, hour_minute_key):
    group_list = list(group)
    hour_minute = time.strftime("%H:%M", time.strptime(group_list[0], "%H:%M:%S"))
    print(f'{hour_minute} occurred {len(group_list)} times')
```

Output:

```
08:54 occurred 4 times
08:55 occurred 6 times
```

Comment: I didn't see this when I posted my answer, but I would say that this is a superior solution as it doesn't use regex.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have mentioned there are better ways to get the output you desire, but if you still want to know how to apply the regex on a list, here's one way:

```py
import re
a = ['08:54:53', '08:54:53', '08:54:54', '08:54:54', '08:55:20', '08:55:20', '08:55:20', '08:55:22', '08:55:23', '08:55:23']
pattern = re.compile("(\d{2}:\d{2}):\d{2}")
hh_mm = map(lambda time: re.search(pattern, time).group(1), a) # Python 2
hh_mm = list(map(lambda time: re.search(pattern, time)[1], a)) # Python 3 

# print output
[print('{} occurs {} times.'.format(time, hh_mm.count(time))) for time in set(hh_mm)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your regex pattern works, but if it does, you can do something like this to apply the pattern to every element in the list:

```
import re
from collections import Counter
a=['08:54:53', '08:54:53', '08:54:54', '08:54:54', '08:55:20', '08:55:20', '08:55:20', '08:55:22', '08:55:23', '08:55:23']
pattern=re.compile("^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:..$")
matches = [m.group(1) for m in filter(None, map(pattern.search,a))]
print(Counter(matches))
```

`map` will apply `pattern.search` to every element in `a` and `filter` will filter that result such that only elements that matched the regex pattern are included.  At this point, you have an iterable containing regex match objects.  Then, a list comprehension is used to create a list where each of the elements in the list is the result of the `m.group(1)` expression.  You may need to modify your regex pattern to make sure that the only capturing group being used is capturing the information you want, or you might need to modify my code slightly (i.e. don't call m.group(1), instead, extract information from the match objects in a different way).  Then, `Counter(matches)` will count the occurrences for you.

I'm not really following your regex pattern, so here's a toy example that shows how my solution is intended to work:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

pattern = re.compile("hello (.+)")
l = ["hello world","hello people","hello guys", "nothing here matches", "hello guys"]
matches = [m.group(1) for m in filter(None, map(pattern.search,l))]
print(Counter(matches))
```

And its output:
`Counter({'guys': 2, 'world': 1, 'people': 1})`

Comment: `Counter` seems to be the right way to go, but your first snippet is printing `Counter({'08': 10})`. I think the MM part of the regex needs a capture-group as well.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't bother testing or modifying the regex pattern, I imagine that's the way it would have to be done though